# Eclipse: JerseyTest.getClient returns RestEasyClient

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jersey, resteasy

I got a project where the `jersey-client` and the `resteasyclient` library is included. This has historic reasons, and since I had to include the resteasyclient , my `junit-tests` return at `jersey-test.getClient()` the `resteasyclient` and I am getting `"RESTEASY004655 Unable to invoke the request"`, when executing the target-method. 
When I am manually excluding the `resteasyclient.jar`, it works.

Is there a way to exclude libraries while testing in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it's crazy. This is just how the JAX-RS `ClientBuilder` is designed<sup>1</sup>; other `ClientBuilder`s on the classpath take precedence over the Jersey `ClientBuilder`. This is only the case when you use the standard JAX-RS `ClientBuilder`, which is what the `JerseyTest` does.

But each implementation comes with their own `ClientBuilder` implementation. For instance, Jersey comes with [`JerseyClientBuilder`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder.java). If you want to use that then you can.

```
Client client = JerseyClientBuilder.createClient();
if (client instance JerseyClient) {
   System.out.println("Hip hip hooray!");
}
```

When using the `JerseyTest`, it gives you the ability to override the default client that is used.

```
@Override
public Client getClient() {
    return JerseyClientBuilder.createClient();
}
```

A couple things to note about this:

1. If you are overriding `configureClient` in the `JerseyTest`, it won't work. You will just need to configure the client in the `getClient()` method.
2. Probably the most important is that it won't work with the in-memory test provider. When using the in-memory test provider, the client is configured with a special in-memory connector. If you want to override the client, then you should use a "real server" test provider, like the grizzly2 one.

---

<sup>1 - If you want to get into the gory details, checkout the source for [ClientBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.java?av=f) and the [FactoryFinder](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax/ws/rs/client/FactoryFinder.java?av=f) that it uses.</sup>